Getting error thrown when trying to retrieve a png in my own google drive using UrlFetchApp.fetch()
I have a script running that creates a qr code for a google form and saves it to my google drive and collects its url. I'm trying to then put that qr code in a google doc. I could have sworn my code was working a month ago, I took a break from it and when I came back it is no longer working. I know some of the qr code generating things were deprecated a while back and just stopped working, and I had to troubleshoot that to get it sorted out. Is that the case with the code below or am I doing something wrong? I tried adding authentication and it didn't help.
My error message (thrown at the UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl) line):

Exception: Request failed for https://drive.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: body{height:100%;margin:0;width:100%}@media (max-height:350px){.button{font-size:10px}.button-... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

// searchText is the text in the google doc I want to replace with the image, 
// docID is the google doc ID to put the image in, 
// imageUrl is my png url which is in my google drive

function insertImage(searchText,docID,imageUrl) {
  // retrieve image
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl);
  image = resp.getBlob();

  // Create a document and insertImage
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docID);
  var totalElements = Doc.getNumChildren();
  var el=[]
  for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
      var element = doc.getChild(j);
      var type = element.getType();
      if (type =='PARAGRAPH'){
          el[j]=element.getText()
          if(el[j]==searchText){element.removeFromParent();// remove the ###
              doc.insertImage(j, image);// 'image' is the image file as blob 
          }
      }
  }
};


Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Are you sure that imageUrl points to a "raw" PNG file rather than to a "view" version that is actually an HTML page? Raw links usually contain&export=download while view links contain /view.

I caught that after and removed the view part of the link but got the same error, should I add that &export=download part as well?

Should this be migrated to [so]?

@Blindspots The question doesn't include enough details for SO.

I was going about it the wrong way. I didn't need to use UrlFetchApp.
I replaced the following two lines
var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl);
image = resp.getBlob();

with
DriveApp.getFileById(imageID).getBlob() 

and it worked!

looks good to me!
